# ASP.NET MVC4 pulling parameter out of url and sending in hidden form value

Tags: model, asp.net-mvc-4, hidden-field

I have a parameter I am passing in a url.  When the user clicks the url they are taken to the site which allows them to enter additional information. (Password Reset)  I need to take the token I pass as part of the url and put it in the model I submit to another controller which verifies the token and password and resets the password if verified.  I can't figure out how to get the passed parameter in the model.

My controller:

```
[AllowAnonymous]
public ActionResult TokenPasswordReset(string token)
{
   return View();
}
```

My url I generate is

```
http://localhost:53272/Account/TokenPasswordReset?wzBXjkT1Y8qmWIECwSIFYQ2
```

In my view I try to set the hidden model value with.

```
<fieldset>
        <legend>Reset Password Form</legend>
        <ol>
            <li>
                @Html.LabelFor(m => m.NewPassword)
                @Html.PasswordFor(m => m.NewPassword)
            </li>
            <li>
                @Html.LabelFor(m => m.ConfirmPassword)
                @Html.PasswordFor(m => m.ConfirmPassword)
            </li>
        </ol>
        @Html.HiddenFor(model.UserToken = Request.Params["token"])
        <input type="submit" value="TokenPasswordReset" />
    </fieldset>
```

The password and confirm password are fine.  I can't figure out how to pull the token out of the url and get it into the model.UserToken.  When I do this I get an error that says

> The name 'model' does not exist in the current context

EDIT: When I change to Model as suggested below I get a new error.  For some reason it does not pick up the Model in the HiddenFor.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Thanks to @Mystere Man and @MVCKarl.  I was able to take components of their answers and solve my issue.  MVCKarls solution seems like it would work, I just didn't want to use ViewData. The URL I generate is this.

```
http://localhost:53272/Account/TokenPasswordReset?Token=LW6lnVrdUXemBMYqluAbMA2
```

In my view I changed the hidden field to this.

```
@Html.Hidden("UserToken", Request.Params["token"])
```

This allowed me to submit it to my controller with only the model passed and I only need to validate the model.

Thanks again...

Answer (score 2):

**Details:** Add your token in a ViewData so that you can access it there in the View.

**Solution:**

In your Controller

```
[AllowAnonymous]
public ActionResult TokenPasswordReset(string token)
{
   ViewData["Token"] = token;

   return View();
}
```

In your view

```
@Html.Hidden("Token", ViewData["Token"])
```

**Updated to complete the problem**

In your Post Method

```
[HttpPost]
public ActionResult TokenPasswordReset(YourModel yourModel, string Token)
{
   yourModel.Token = Token;
   rest of your code....
}
```

Comment: While technically, that addresses the problem he's having, it doesn't really solve his complete problem.

Comment: Is it ok to use ViewData to pass data to views and then onto other controllers?  I read several posts saying not to use it so I only typically use it for messages which are not really critical.

Answer (score 2):

It's `Model`, not `model`.

However, even with that it still won't work.  Notice your url doesn't have a token querystring?  It's just ?gibberish rather than ?token=gibberish.

Also, if you want to pass it as a model item, you must create a model for it:

```
public class TokenModel {
    public string Token {get;set;}
}
```

then in your controller:

```
return View(new TokenModel() { Token = token });
```

Comment: Thanks for the response.  I do have my model set up.  However when I make it Model it says "the type arguments cannot be inferred from the usage.  Try inferring explicitly.

Comment: @Xaxum - did you add an `@model` declaration at the top of your view?

Comment: Yes. It picks up the Passwords just fine.  and if I put the token in the same labelfor and fields so the user can type them in it works fine.  It is just the Hiddenfor that has the issue.  I am testing Hidden now that doesn't seem to throw up the same compile error at least.  Will update once I finish, but may have it.

Comment: @Xaxum - are you still using this: `@Html.HiddenFor(model.UserToken = Request.Params["token"])`?  that won't work.  You need to just say `@Html.HiddenFor(x => x.UserToken)`

Comment: I am using @Html.Hidden("UserToken", Request.Params["token"]) which at least compiles and passes to the next action.  I am in the process of writing the next action to see if the model is complete.  If this doesn't work I will try what you mentioned above.